# Zend Framework 2 Child Regex Routing

Tags: php, regex, routes, tree, zend-framework2

I have desperately been battling with ZF2, I am trying to create a route tree, so that:

- /manual - Goes to the Manual Controller, index action
- /manual/[something] - Goes to the Manual Controller, manufacturer action
- /manual/[something]/[else] - Goes to the Manual Controller, category action
- /manual/[something]/[else]/[foo] - Goes to the Manual Controller, model action

I've used the official docs and several other websites but all I've been able to do is trigger:

- /manual - Goes to the Manual Controller, index action
- /manual/[something] - Goes to the Manual Controller Constructor, but not the action...

The other two dont reach the controller at all....

```
        'manual' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/manual',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Applicaton\Controller\Manual',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // Segment route for viewing one blog post
                'manufacturer' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:manufacturer]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'manufacturer' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'manufacturer'
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'category' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/[:category]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'category' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'action' => 'category'
                                )
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                'model' => array(
                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/[:model]',
                                        'constraints' => array(
                                            'model' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'action' => 'model'
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
```

Thanks for your help in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Update:

Here is my controller action:

```
public function manufacturerAction() {
    echo 'I am in the manufacturer action!';
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using regular expressions. Modify your routes in **module.config.php** as follows

```
'manual' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/manual',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Manual',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
'manufacturer' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/manual/(?<manufacturer>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Manual',
            'action' => 'manufacturer',
        ),
        'spec' => '/manual/%manufacturer%',
    ),
),
'category' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/manual/(?<manufacturer>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<category>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Manual',
            'action' => 'category',
        ),
        'spec' => '/manual/%manufacturer%/%category%',
    ),
),
'model' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/manual/(?<manufacturer>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<category>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<model>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Manual',
            'action' => 'model',
        ),
        'spec' => '/manual/%manufacturer%/%category%/%model%',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Hi Finny, This worked almost perfectly except the 'manufacturer' route doesn't work, it makes it to the Controller, but its unable to dispatch the request. I've added the controller action above, but its pretty standard...

Comment: Hi Ben, Can you provide some specifics on the issue you have; like the url you're trying to access and your updated route?

Comment: Hi Finny, my updated route is exactly as you have it above. My URL would be http://v2.mydomain/manual/nikon , it doesn't matter what I put in the last part of the URL it does reach the 'manufacturer action'...

Comment: @Ben You have to capture the route and do the appropriate.
In manufacturerAction() use the following to get the route parameter;
**$manufacturer = $this->params()->fromRoute('manufacturer');**

As of the url given; **$manufacturer** will be populated as **nikon**